# when i use the Log4j 1.x bridge (log4j-1.2-api)，but Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter

Tags: java, maven, logging, log4j, log4j2

log4j2 performs better, but the jar in my dependencies uses log4j, which causes warnings. Because it depends on slf4j-log4j12. So I follow documents: *https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html#Log4j1.2Bridge*
The slf4j-log4j12 dependency is excluded, and the following dependencies are added: When I run the program, the service in the package I depend on doesn't start, and I get an error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
```

```
    <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
```

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lmax</groupId>
            <artifactId>disruptor</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

** What should I do to make sure I'm using log4j2 and still compatible with packaging-dependent log4j**

Comment: The missing class [`Log4jLoggerAdapter`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.25/org/slf4j/impl/Log4jLoggerAdapter.html) is part of `log4j-slf4j12`. This means you didn't entirely exclude this artifact. Check with `mvn dependency:tree`.